# Homer Simpson Doh moment: Node modules accidentally uploaded to cloud

Tags: icloud, filesystem, storage

I am a programmer, and use ICloud to back up my personal files. Recently, when trying to find a file on my ICloud, I noticed that it was full of the content of one of my programming projects' source code folder

known as `@node_modules`- this is not the code I wrote, but rather, a massive folder containing thousands of folders of other resources that help the framework I write my
programs in operate.

So, I have no idea how this happened. I ended up having to comb the ICloud folder and manually delete all the node modules files which were uploaded. It was a huge pain resolving, and I'd like to avoid doing it again in the future.

To my best guess, this happened because of some kind of automatic upload. But I have no record of what gets uploaded by using my system file explorer. and the ICloud program I installed does not offer much in the way of that either.

Is there some kind of helper program for ICloud, which I can leverage, to gain better control over how my ICloud storage is used. specifically, I was hoping for these features:

1. ask me to confirm, before uploads,
2. allows me to customize how/when things are uploaded automatically- so that i can prevent what just happened
3. back-up/ restore the storage to a restore point. or otherwise undo a large amount of files/ folders being uploaded by mistake.

Please note, I am a windows user, so when I say "the file explorer does not offer much in the way..." I am actually talking about windows 10 file explorer/ not MacOs file explorer, which I would assume offers better support of cloud storage.

Comment: When you installed node.js where did you request its files to be saved - or are you using a package manger like npm on top of it?

Comment: iclkoud is a simple system - it uploads all under the Documents directory. For code I would suggest putting it in a different directory and then use another backup method - possibly copying some files to ~/Documents

Comment: So not an iCloud or Apple problem but Windows so on topic?

Comment: Well it is an understanding of node problem - in relation to iCloud

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926672/where-does-npm-install-packages npm will put all the external js code you are using in the node_modules sub-directory of your current code.

Comment: @mmmmmm thank you. yes, I am using npm. and yes, the node modules is saved in my project. I dont keep my code in documents, and also, it only uploaded the content of node modules, not the entire project. roughly the path is something like ```C:\<user>\VsCode\webdevelopment\<projectName>\.node_modules```

Comment: The path is not like that as that is a Microsoft path. What is the exact path?

Comment: @mmmmmm yes I am using ICloud with Windows 10 OS. hence my hoping you could clarify what you said about the documents folder being uploaded... perhaps it is different with windows? (in the past, I usually just copy and pasted files/folders I wanted to upload to the cloud. wasnt aware it uploaded contents of specific folders by default)

Comment: @mmmmmm since it is windows. documents is here ```C:\users\ben\documents``` and node modules is here ```C:\users\vsCode\webdev\someproject\node modules```, there is no overlap.